# how to extract final coefficient values from lm

Tags: r, lm

I want to extract the "final values" of my diferent intercept values.

This is my model where `ruido = 1` and `ruido = 2`:

```
lm.color0 <- lm(RT.ms ~ TransDist*as.factor(ruido), data = BO.hits.sinOuts.Lum13.Color0)

summary(lm.color0)

#Coefficients:
#                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)                 451.25190    5.03016  89.709  < 2e-16 ***
#TransDist                     2.54787    0.04309  59.126  < 2e-16 ***
#as.factor(ruido)2            21.59586    7.16326   3.015  0.00258 ** 
#TransDist:as.factor(ruido)2   0.34196    0.06098   5.608  2.1e-08 ***
```

I know that for `ruido=1`:

```
#(Intercept)                 451.25190 ("final value)
#TransDist                     2.54787 ("final value)
```

and for `ruido=2`:

```
#(Intercept)                 451.25190 + 21.59586 (from as.factor(ruido)2) = 472,84776 ("final value")
#TransDist                     2.54787 + 0.34196 (TransDist:as.factor(ruido)2) = 2,88983 ("final value")
```

I want to extract this "final values" for both `ruidos` directly, is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str()` to see the structure of any object in R.  So run this in your R console:

```
str(lm.color0)
```

This will show you the structure of yur `lm` model.  You will notice a field accessible with `$` called "coefficients".  It is then trivial for you to combine them as needed.

```
lm.color0$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]]
lm.color0$coefficients[["TransDist"]]

lm.color0$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]] + lm.color0$coefficients[["as.factor(ruido)2"]]
lm.color0$coefficients[["TransDist"]] + lm.color0$coefficients[["TransDist:as.factor(ruido)2"]]
```